# How can I implement a directive that wraps its HostElement's content in a div?

Tags: angular

I need to implement a directive that adds HTML elements inside of its Host Element, while also putting all of the element's content in a specific part of the HTML, essentially wrapping the content, just like how Angular Material wraps the content of `<button mat-button>` with a `<span class="mat-button-wrapper">`.

For instance, the component would be put in a template like this:

```
<div my-directive>
    my text
</div>
```

And this should be rendered:

```
<div my-directive>
    <div class="my-class">
        my text
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using a WrapperComponent and adding it to the directive's ViewContainerRef, like shown below.

```
import { Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, Component, Renderer2, ElementRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChild, ComponentRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-wrapper',
    template: `
        <div class="my-wrapper">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
    `
})
export class WrapperComponent {
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[wrapContent]'
})
export class WrapContentDirective{

    wrapperRef: ComponentRef<WrapperComponent>;

    constructor(
        private renderer: Renderer2,
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private vcr: ViewContainerRef,
        private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        hostElement: ElementRef
    ) {
        const wrapperFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(WrapperComponent);
        this.wrapperRef = this.vcr.createComponent(wrapperFactory);
    }
}
```

But the wrapper is rendered next to the element, and not inside it. And I still need to figure out how to project the content of ng-content into the WrapperComponent.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a component with your desired template, I am calling it DynoComponent. This component will be created dynamically and template will be set on it to be used with `[ngTemplateOutlet]`.

Create a directive which will capture the `TemplateRef` and `ViewContainerRef` of the host and create the `DynoComponent` dynamically and set the template property on it.

**DynoComponent html**

```
<div class="my-class">
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]='template'></ng-template>
</div>
```

**DynoComponent ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dyno',
  templateUrl: './dyno.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dyno.component.css']
})
export class DynoComponent implements OnInit {

  template: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**my directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appMyDirective]'
})
export class MyDirectiveDirective implements OnInit {
  compRef: ComponentRef<DynoComponent>;
  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef,
              private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
              private compFact: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const myComp = this.compFact.resolveComponentFactory(DynoComponent);
    this.compRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(myComp);
    this.compRef.instance.template = this.templateRef;
  }

}
```

**How to use in other templates**

```
<div class="outer" *appMyDirective>
  <p>inside content</p>
</div>
```

**Output**

```
<div _ngcontent-acn-c18="" class="my-class">
    <div _ngcontent-acn-c20="" class="outer">
        <p _ngcontent-acn-c20="">inside content</p>
    </div>
    <!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet": "[object Object]"
    }-->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've considered using a Structural Directive, but I was trying to avoid having to use *directive. I guess that's the right way to do it, though. I wonder how Angular Material does it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You could add a setter input with same name as directive of  type TemplateRef and use it on host element like [appMyDirective]=‘templateRef’ where templateRef could be a local reference to ng-template. Basically this way you wouldn’t have to use *.

Comment: I just tested it out. It works but my goal was to wrap only the element's content. The solution wraps everything, including the element originally attached to the directive.